Ubuntu 22 split screen windows acting as if they are linked, how can I disable this?
I will describe the behavior/how I reproduce it, as I do not know if there is a name for this 'feature' or if it is intentional in the first place and search has failed me.

Open window 1 and drag to left side of monitor to create half screen window
Click blank desktop space to close the window selection popup
Open window 2 and drag to the right side of monitor to create half screen window
Open window 3 and drag to either side to create half screen window
Click uncovered window opposite window 3
Window 3 goes to the background (not minimized) and whatever window was behind it is displayed in foreground

This happens with windows on both left and right, and across multiple apps.
How can I disable this behavior entirely, or at least 'unlink' windows when they get grouped like this?

This sounds like "Tile Groups" from "Enhanced Tiling" on Ubuntu 24.04. I had a related question on the topic, but I'm now on 22.04, and don't see this behavior or a related option.

@drmuelr Wow, can't believe I forgot I had installed that as an extension some time ago. I appreciate your input, it was enough to jog my memory and know where to fix the issue! I will post that as the answer in case anyone else has a similar brain malfunction.

As drmuelr alluded to in the comments, this is a feature from Ubuntu 24 which has been backported through the Tiling Assistant by Leleat gnome extension that I had installed some time ago, and forgotten about before noticing this behavior.
I was able to disable the popup and behavior as desired through the gnome extensions browser interface:

